# Shell Script on Boot up does not execute on Raspberry pi

Tags: linux, bash, raspberry-pi, raspbian, init.d

I want to run the following commands just after bootup of Raspberry Pi running the raspbian wheezy:

1. `sudo gcc -lpthread server.c -o wifiserver.o`
2. `sudo ./wifiserver.o`

I created the following files and ran the following steps:

1. Created a script file named `auto_server_start`.
2. Contents are as follows:

   ```
   #!bin/bash
   # /etc/init.d/auto_server_start
   ### BEGIN INIT INFO
   # Provides: auto_server_start
   # Required-Start: $all
   # Required-Stop: $remote_fs $syslog
   # Default-Start: 2 3 4 5
   # Default-Stop: 0 1 6
   # Short-Description: wifi server script
   # Description: Start wifi server at bootup
   ### END INIT INFO

   case "$1" in
     start)
       echo "running server program"
       sudo gcc -lpthread server.c -o wifiserver.o
       sudo ./wifiserver.o
       ;;
     stop)
       echo "stopping customized script"
       ;;
     *)
       echo "Usage: /etc/init.d/auto_server_start start|stop"
       exit 1
       ;; 
   esac

   exit 0
   ```
3. Copied this file named `auto_server_start` to `/etc/init.d/` directory and added execute permission using `chmod +x`.
4. Then `sudo update-rc.d auto_server_start defaults`.

It gave some warning about mathkernel but I don't think that has anything to do with my script.

However on soft reboot I checked `ps -e` as well as `top`, nowhere does my `wifiserver` process show up.

Please suggest.

PS: I checked that the commands `gcc` and `./wifiserver.o` were giving no warning and errors.

Comment: Why would you recompile the binary on reboot??

Comment: `sudo` is pointless and potentially harmful here. An init script already has all the privileges it needs.

Comment: Put the compiled binary into `/usr/local/bin` and change the script to run it from there. Examine your system log for failure or warning messages. Post them here if you need help interpreting them.

Comment: Hi it worked thanks ... I put the executable in the /usr/local/bin folder... I was not providing the file path properly...i guess it would have worked with /home/pi/wifiserver.o as well since my executable was present there. Thanks!! @tripleee

Comment: Post the fixed script as an answer and accept it so that this question no longer shows up as unresolved.  Thanks.

Comment: A "/" is missing in the shebang : #!/bin/bash

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Created a script file named auto_server_start.

Contents are as follows:

```
\#!bin/bash

\# /etc/init.d/auto_server_start

\### BEGIN INIT INFO

\# Provides: auto_server_start

\# Required-Start: $all

\# Required-Stop: $remote_fs $syslog

\# Default-Start: 2 3 4 5

\# Default-Stop: 0 1 6

\# Short-Description: wifi server script

\# Description: Start wifi server at bootup

\### END INIT INFO


case "$1" in

  start)

    echo "running server program"

    /usr/local/bin/wifiserver.o

    ;;

  stop)

    echo "stopping customized script"

    ;;

  *)

    echo "Usage: /etc/init.d/auto_server_start start|stop"

    exit 1

    ;; 

esac


exit 0
```

Copied this file named auto_server_start to /etc/init.d/ directory and added execute permission using chmod +x.

Then sudo update-rc.d auto_server_start defaults.